# R Shiny change height of plot

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I am trying to set the height of a plot, but cant seem to get the height parameter in the plot function to actually do anything. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
  output$probability_chart <- renderPlot({
    xvals <- 1:17 
    req(input$countrySelectProbabilities)
    idx <- which(input$countrySelectProbabilities==FVI_DATA_ALL_COUNTRIES)

    max_comp_prob <- max(Composite_Probabilities_1_DF[idx, 2:18], na.rm=TRUE)
    max_bank_prob <- max(Banking_Probabilities_1_DF[idx, 2:18], na.rm=TRUE)
    max_curr_prob <- max(Currency_Probabilities_1_DF[idx, 2:18], na.rm=TRUE)
    max_sove_prob <- max(Sovereign_Probabilities_1_DF[idx, 2:18], na.rm=TRUE)
    max_sudd_prob <- max(Sudden_Stop_Probabilities_1_DF[idx, 2:18], na.rm=TRUE)

    overall_max_prob <- max(max_comp_prob, max_bank_prob, max_curr_prob, max_sove_prob, max_sudd_prob, na.rm=TRUE)


    plot(x = xvals, y=Composite_Probabilities_1_DF[idx, 2:18], type = "l"
         , xlab = "", ylab = "", col="grey20", ylim = c(-10, overall_max_prob), lwd=3, las=2)
    mtext("Financial Vulnerability Indicator", side=3, adj=0, line=1.2, cex=2, font=2)
    mtext("Probability", side=3, adj=0, line=0.1, cex=1, font=0.5)
    axis(1,at=xvals,label=dates, cex.axis=1, las=2)
    lines(xvals, Banking_Probabilities_1_DF[idx, 2:18], col="green2", lwd=3)
    lines(xvals, Currency_Probabilities_1_DF[idx, 2:18], col="purple", lwd=3)
    lines(xvals, Sovereign_Probabilities_1_DF[idx, 2:18], col="red", lwd=3)
    lines(xvals, Sudden_Stop_Probabilities_1_DF[idx, 2:18], col="orange", lwd=3)
    legend(
      "bottom", 
      lty=c(1,1,1,1), 
      lwd=c(3,3,3,3), 
      col=c("grey20", "green2", "purple", "red", "orange"), 
      legend = c("Composite", "Banking", "Currency", "Sovereign", "Sudden Stop")
      ,ncol=5
    )
  })
```

Comment: There is a height parameter in `renderPlot`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Ah yes, my bad, that does work. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped. BTW, you can also define height as a function in case you want dependence on inputs or reactive values.

Answer (score 8):

In `server.R` You should add height argument next to `plotOutput`:

```
 plotOutput("plot", height=800)
```

Comment: note that the ``height`` attribute can also be an ``input$somefield``.

Comment: @DenisCousineau no it cannot. You would get `Can't access reactive value 'somefield' outside of reactive consumer.` error.

Comment: @SarenTasciyan Well... this is exactly what I did and it works like a charm. See file App.R on [Github](https://github.com/dcousin3/superb/blob/master/inst/superbShiny/App.R), line 388, and a live demonstration on [Shinyapps.io](https://dcousin3.shinyapps.io/superbshiny/).

Comment: @DenisCousineau Thanks I have somehow confused it with renderPlot, which I was trying. Interesting that it works in the ui code.